# Indicate a Input Value is the Primary Unit

Tags: forms, interface, long-forms

I'm currently putting together a UI content block that would allow a user to select a unit, unit size, position and input the needed crew values. The end user should be able to determine whether or not the initial squadron size is the primary value in this simple equation:

Sqd 15 - Sqd10 = Difference of 5

Not entirely married to the current idea of the Primary Value checkbox after the Sqd size number input and was wondering if someone out there ma have a better approach.

[image: AH-1Z TMS]
[image: AH-1Z Select a Unit Size Group]
[image: New Position Added]

Comment: What is the primary value checkbox? Why is it there?

Comment: The TMS (AH-1Z) may have multiple positions added. Each position has a has squadron unit sizes. The checkbox signifies that the value in the Sqd([value]) for that position is setting the primary unit size. The unit size multiselect above the number inputs identifies which labeled number inputs to use.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logic provided in the form, it seems like adding the Primary Value input would be redundant if there was only one position entered. If this is the most common use case, then I would say you don't show this by default.

If the user normally decides which of the positions is going to be used as the Primary Value, you can either show a radio button like you did AFTER the squad value input fields.

[image]

Or, if it is common to enter in quite a few positions and you have to choose from say more than five, you can implement a dropdown instead.

[image]